# ResponseStatusException - response body missing

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.1'
```

Following is the code snippet I am using for throwing the exception

```
catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            throw new ResponseStatusException(
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "something went wrong",e);
        }
```

In response, we are getting 400 without a response body

```
 * upload completely sent off: 100 out of 100 bytes
    * Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
    < HTTP/1.1 400 
    < Vary: Origin
    < Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
    < Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
    < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    < X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    < Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    < Pragma: no-cache
    < Expires: 0
    < X-Frame-Options: DENY
    < Content-Length: 0
    < Date: Thu, 27 Oct 2022 14:43:38 GMT
    < Connection: close
    < 
    * Closing connection 0
```

UPDATE: application.properties has the following config

```
server.error.include-message=always
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from 2.3, Spring Boot doesn't include an error message on the default error page. The reason is to reduce the risk of leaking information to a client.

To change the default behavior, you can set the server.error.include-message property:

```
server.error.include-message=always
```

Source:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#changes-to-the-default-error-pages-content

Comment: server.error.include-message=always  - I have added this in application.properties file already, but it didn't make a difference. And isn't this configuration only for the error messages in the response body? In my case, the entire response body is missing.